# How to access an integer in an array in assembly with pointer?

Tags: assembly, x86

First of all, this is a homework assignment. I was told to create a sorting function with these parameters using push and pop. They are passed in the function like this, and I don't know how to access the elements in it with "int *list". I'm in the middle of the process

```
    int sorter (int* list, int count, int opcode)
    {
    __asm
    {
   mov eax, 0; zero out the result
   mov ebx, opcode; move opcode to ebx for comparison
   ; fill in your code here
   mov ecx, 0; set the counter to 0
   cmp ebx, 0x01; check ascendant or descendant
   je ASCENDANT
   jne DESCENDANT
   ASCENDANT:
   loop_start :
   cmp ecx, count; condition for the outer loop
   jge loop_end
   push ecx
   mov eax,
   }
   }



 loop_start:
   cmp ecx, count   ; condition for the outer loop
   jge loop_end     ; jump if end of array
   mov esi, list    ; move pointer to esi
   mov eax, [esi + 4 * ecx] ; move data that current index to eax
   push ecx         ; push ecx to the stack to save the index
   inner_loop:
     inc ecx        ; increment eax
     cmp eax, [esi + 4 * ecx]; compare eax with the next element in the array
     jle swap       ; if it is less than the current value than jump to swap
     cmp ecx, count ; check if ecx reaches the end of array
     jle inner_loop ; if not than go back to inner loop
     pop ecx        ; it ecx reaches the end than pop eax to go back to the old index of outer loop
     mov[esi + 4 * ecx], eax ; exchange the value of current eax to the element that is compared
     inc ecx        ; increment ecx for outer loop
     jmp loop_start ; jump back to loop start
     swap:          ; swap the smaller value with the current value
     mov eax, [esi + 4 * ecx] ; swapping
   jmp inner_loop   ; jump back to inner loop
 loop_end:
 ret
```

Comment: `jle inner_loop` looks suspicious. If `ecx` equals `count` and you jump back to `inner_loop`, the first thing you'll do is increment `ecx` and compare against something that is outside of the array,

Comment: but if I dont increase ecx, it would compare its current element with itself for the first time. I tried to increase eax after checking "jle swap" and I ran into an infinite loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place the value of `list` (i.e. the address of the `int`s) in a register, and use register-indirect addressing:

```
mov esi, list   
mov eax, [esi]  ; read the first element
mov eax, [esi+4]  ; read the second element
add esi, 8  ; move 2 elements ahead
mov eax, [esi]  ; read the third element
; etc...
```

If you want to swap two elements in the array specified by indices in `ecx` and `edx` you could do:

```
mov eax, [esi + ecx*4]    ; eax = elem1
xchg eax, [esi + edx*4]   ; swap eax and elem2
mov [esi + ecx*4], eax    ; elem2 = old elem1
```

Comment: Thank you so much, but how do I swap the smaller value in the array with a value of a certain index in the array?

Comment: Thank you so much again! I have a question. If I push ecx (the counter) to the stack, will the data of ecx still remain on it? Because I want to keep the index for my outer loop, and get it back after ecx finish the inner loop? Also, are there any ways that I can contact you?

Comment: Pushing `ecx` doesn't modify `ecx`.

Comment: I finished my bubble sorting, but it keeps crashing, can you take a look at it and help me with it please? Sorry, I'm very new to Assembly.

Comment: Now I have an array of structures with each element is (int ID, char name[20]). I'm given a pointer 'char* list'. I passed it to esi. How can I read each character of the name. I tried to do this: 'mov esi, list' -> 'add esi, 4' -> mov al, byte ptr[esi+ ecx]-> 'inc ecx' -> 'add esi, 24'. Is it a right way to appoarch? Thanks

Comment: Separate questions should be posted as new questions rather than as comments.

Comment: At first, I was afraid of doing that because it's assignment and it's due yet, so there are several reasons why I did not do it. However, I decided to do so. Please help [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31486707/how-to-compare-strings-by-character-case-insensitive-assembly)

Answer (score 2):

x86 CPUs support index addressing like:

```
mov edx, list                      ;edx is a list ptr
mov ecx, index                     ;ecx ia an array index 
mov eax, dword ptr[edx + ecx * 4]  ;Load result to eax
```

Comment: if I find a smaller value , how can I swap it with the value of a current index? Thanks a lot

Comment: Keep the index of both in a register, and then simply load the value into eax (or some other convenient register) and store it at the other address: `mov eax,[esi + ecx*4] : mov ebx,[esi + edx*4] : mov [esi + edx*4],eax : mov [esi + ecx*4],ebx` or similar.