# Trying to do case insensitive search in assembly and my code doesn't work

Tags: assembly, x86

I have an array of structures with each element is a number and street name

```
struct house
{
    int number;
    char streetName[20];
}
```

I want to search it with a token passed in. Here is my code, and I don't know why it does not work. Please help!

```
mov eax, 0   ; zero out the result
mov esi, list    ; move the list pointer to ESI
mov edi, token   ; move the pointer of token string to edi
mov edx, 0       ; reset edx counter
mov ecx, 0       ; reset ecx counter
L1:
mov eax, [esi+4] ; read number of street into eax
add esi, 4       ; move pointer 4 bytes to start reading street name
L2:
mov al, byte ptr[esi + ecx]; mov each char of street name from array to al
mov bl, byte ptr[edi + ecx]; mov each char of search token to bl
or al, 20h       ; convert al (case insensitive)
or bl, 20h       ; convert bl (case insensitive)
inc ecx          ; prepare next char
cmp al, bl       ; cmp al and bl
jne DIFFERENT    ; jump to DIFFERENT if different
cmp bl, 0        ; check if bl reaches to the end of the string
je done          ; jump if all match to done
jmp L2           ; jump back to L2 to check the next char
DIFFERENT:
add esi, 24      ; add esi 24 bytes to move the pointer to the next item of structure array
mov ecx, 0       ; reset the counter ecx
inc edx          ; inc the edx counter for structure array
cmp edx, count   ; check if it reaches the end of array
je not_found     ; if reaching the end but found nothing then jmp to not found
jmp L1           ; jump back to L1
not_found: 
mov eax, 0       ; set eax to 0 to indicate not found
done:
```

Comment: You don't say what assembler, but since you use `ptr` you may also need `offset` (on `list` and `token` ?).

Comment: when you do `cmp bl, 0` you have already OR-ed `bl` with 20h. That condition is always false and the check go past the end of the token and street name string. Also set an upper bound on the inner cycle (i.e. on `ecx`) to 20.

Comment: I put info on using gdb for asm into http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info the other day.  The idea was so questions like this could be answered with just that link.

Comment: @knm241. I did move the codes so that it checks `bl` first before it converts the case, but it still does not work. Do you have any ideas? Thanks

Comment: I was all excited that this was a question about case insensitivity and searches in Assembly only to discover that it's yet another, "Why doesn't this code work?" :(

Answer (score 3):

```
L1:
mov eax, [esi+4] ; read number of street into eax
add esi, 4       ; move pointer 4 bytes to start reading street name
L2:
mov al, byte ptr[esi + ecx]; mov each char of street name from array to al
```

In this part of your code it is useless to read the *number of street* since you use AL afterwards to process the characters.

Because of this, what do you hope this program to produce when the strings match? At least AL would be 0 (street numbers are usually small numbers?) and you defined EAX=0 as the signal for not found!

I propose the following to leave a sensible value in the EAX register:

```
L2:
mov bh, byte ptr[esi + ecx]; mov each char of street name from array to bh
mov bl, byte ptr[edi + ecx]; mov each char of search token to bl
cmp bl, 0        ; check if bl reaches to the end of the string
je done          ; jump if all match to done
or bx, 2020h     ; convert both characters at once (case insensitive)
inc ecx          ; prepare next char
cmp bh, bl       ; cmp bh and bl
je L2            ; jump back to L2 to check the next char
DIFFERENT:
```

You only test for the terminating zero of the *token string*. But what happens when the *array string* does not have the same length? Your program can only work when both strings have the same length.

Comment: Nice analysis of some major problems, without just doing his homework for him.

Comment: @baopham: Well I guess I was a bit rude in a passive-aggressive way.    There have been several other people posting low-quality questions about x86 asm recently, and I took it out on you.  I did post an answer with links to a debugger and other stuff that can help you out.  Was that helpful at all?  If no, what are some things that you found for yourself that did help, so we can add them to http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info, so they'll be there for other x86 asm beginners?

Comment: Did the info about how to use GDB (`layout asm`, `layout reg`) in the tag wiki help?  I linked it because it explains *how* to set up gdb for debugging asm.  I'm not a moderator or adming, just a guy who sees questions from people like you, new to asm and confused about things.  Often there isn't a question beyond "my code doesn't work, help", which is officially not what SO is supposed to be for.  Having a good here's-what-you-need link to throw into answers like that is ideal, to get the asker going with a debugger on their own, so the rest of the answer can be specific to their code.

Answer (score 1):

[The x86 tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info) page has info on using a debugger, as well as guides and other resources.  This is exactly the kind of problem that's ideal for solving yourself with a debugger.  You would see your branch not branching when you expected, due to the bug that knm241 pointed out.